# how to set a webservice as a scheduled task in windows

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-services

I am writing a console application in c#. How can I set the console application to run as a scheduled task in windows?

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task) how you schedule a task in Windows 7. You point the task at the .exe of your console application.